# Dependency injection in php?

Tags: php, oop, dependency-injection

I am currently building a little project with PHP whilst not using any static methods or global state.

My class' constructors currently look a little like this, I am just injecting the dependent objects upon creating an object instance.

```
class Something {

     public function __construct(Name\Space\Object $object, Other\Name\Space $object2) 
     {
         # Assign properties here
     }
}
```

In one of my application's classes I need to create new instances of various objects through the calling of its methods. Something a little like below;

```
class Something {

     public function getNewObject()
     {
         return new Name\Space\Object();
     }

     public function getNewObject2()
     {
         return new Name\Space\ObjectTwo();
     }
}
```

Is this how it should be done whilst adhering to the standard rule of dependency injection?

I am unsure how else it could be done as if I inject the object into the constructor then I will only have one instance whereas I may need many within my application?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that functions are first class objects in PHP, so this should work:

```
<?php
class MyClass {
  function foo() {
    return 'foo';
  }
};

class MyOtherClass {
  function __construct($klass) {
      $this->klass = $klass;
  }

  function get_instance() {
    return new $this->klass();
  }
}

$factory = new MyOtherClass(MyClass);
$obj     = $factory->get_instance();
?>
// <h1> value should equal foo
<h1><?php echo $obj->foo();?></h1>
```

Edit: Tested and works.

Comment: This looks cool, will implement a test and let you know how I get on. This is a better solution than mine if it works, thanks.

Comment: This solution does work, just pass the class name into the constructor and you're good. You can also reassign the class at runtime by clobbering the $klass property.